# How to get column number of the log record in logging module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am trying to format log records in Python 3 from the `logging` module. I want to know the line number and column number where the error/warning occurred. I see the line number can be used from `%(lineno)d` LogRecord attribute, but couldn't find the column number as an attribute. How do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an attribute for the column number, because there is probably no a use case for it. It is not a syntax error when a parser tells you the exact location (line and column) of the character that it was not able to parse.

With logging I write a log message and usually I just want to know the file name and the line in which this log message was written. For example:

```
logger.info("This is my log message")
```

What the value of the column attribute should be in this case? What will it tell you?

Comment: I am trying to format the logs to match the GitHub workflow commands in the following way:  `::error file=app.py,line=10,col=15::Something went wrong`

Comment: @ShubhanshuSaxena I don't understand this. In my example code line what is col number that you would expect? Please extend your question with a code example and the exact expected log message.